# Meteor: Injecting via "meteor add" vs using "<script>" tag

Tags: javascript, meteor, atmosphere.js

I was trying to inject Datatables library into my meteor app, but I found that meteor doesn't *always* include the file injected via the `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
```

However, when I add the same file via an atmosphere package, it somehow does the job:

```
meteor add ksrv:datatables
```

Look at the [source code](https://github.com/ksrv/datatables/) for this package on github. It has just one file, which is exactly the **same file** I was trying to include earlier, but via `<script>` tag, and somehow, that works.

What is the difference between injecting files via `<script>` tags in the HTML file, and injecting files via atmosphere meteor packages?

Comment: Meteor doesn't include things that way - you should install a package either using an atmosphere package or npm

Comment: Yes, but things like jQuery are working fine even after including using `<script>` instead of the meteor package

Comment: jQuery is standalone, while datatables depends on jQuery. Meteor bundles source files, enforcing dependencies. Having external dependencies included as `<script>` tags does not let you control load order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Meteor development there are no patterns for using a `<script>` tag in html. Javascript functionality is added via:

1. Meteor packages: `meteor add packagename`
2. npm packages: `npm install packagename`
3. Your own js code.

The meteor build system deals with adding all the above into your application. In a development environment you will see every script loaded individually into your HTML. In a production deployment all the javascript, both packages and your own code, is minified and concatenated into a single script that is loaded into your single page application.